# Saving GPU memory by bypassing GUI

Tags: linux, macos, cuda, gpu

I have a mac book pro with a 2 Gb Nvidia GPU. I am trying to utilize all my GPU memory for computations (python code). How much saving I may get if I bypassed the GUI interface and only accessed my machine through command line. I want to know if such a thing would save me a good amount of GPU memory?

Comment: why don't you try it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference probably won't be huge.

A GPU that is only hosting a console display will only typically have ~5-25 megabytes of memory reserved out of the total memory size.    On the other hand, a GPU that is hosting a GUI display (using the NVIDIA GPU driver) might typically have ~50 megabytes or more reserved for display use (this may vary somewhat based on the size of the display attached).

So you can probably get a good "estimate" of the savings by running `nvidia-smi` and looking at the difference between total and available memory for your GPU with the GUI running.  If that is, for example, 62MB, then you can probably "recover" around 40-50MB by shutting off the GUI, for example on linux switching to runlevel 3.

I just ran this experiment on a linux laptop with a Quadro3000M that happens to have 2GB of memory.  With the X display up and NVIDIA GPU driver loaded, the "used" memory was 62MB out of 2047MB (reported by `nvidia-smi`).

When I switch to runlevel 3 (X is not started) the memory usage dropped to about 4MB.  That probably means that ~50MB additional is available to CUDA.

A side benefit of shutting off the GUI might be the elimination of [the display watchdog](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).